# $W(s)[W(t)-W(s)]$ Independence for Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

If $0\leq s<t$, then the $W(s)$ and $W(t)-W(s)$ are independent.

How can we deduce this from the definition of Brownian motion?

Specifically, I know one time step (i.e. $[t,t+1]$) increments are independent, but we do not know how many time steps are apart from $s$ to $t$.

My intuition is that you can write $W(s)$ and $W(t)-W(s)$ as telescoping sum with how many one time-unit increments as possible and the product would always yield the cross-product of one-time step increment cross-products, so in effect, they are independent?

Comment: What is your definition of Brownian Motion? In the definition I'm familiar with, it is said that increments are independent

Comment: The definition I have is that for a finite set, $\{t_1,...,t_m\}$ that $W_{i+1}-W_i$ is defined as increments. So that's why I got confused if we arbitrarily know $s<t$, we don't know they are one-time step apart, right? So in the definition you understood, it doesn't have to be one-time step apart to be called "increment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independent increments means  $\{W_{t_{i+1}} -W_{t_i}: 1\leq ,m\}$ is an independent collection whenever $t_1<t_2<...<t_n$.  There is no restriction on the valaues of the numbers $t_{i+1}-t_i$ in this definition. Taking $t_1=0, t_2=s$ and $t_3=t$ we get the result.

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks!!